# No me sale el ejercicio del rombo con numeros en java

Tags: java, bucles

Ejercicio :

```
/*5) Escribe un programa que lea un número n entero comprendido entre 1 y 9, e imprima una pirámide de números con 
n filas como en la siguiente figura:

        1
       121
      12321
     1234321
    123454321
   12345654321
  1234567654321
 123456787654321
12345678987654321

*/
```

Lo que me imprime

````
     1
    123
   12345
  1234567
 123456789

*/```
````

El código :

```
package examen1Tr;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio5 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Escribe el numero de fila : ");
        int max = teclado.nextInt();
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        if (max % 2 == 0) {
            max++;
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= max; i = i + 2) {
            for (k = max + 1; k >= i; k = k - 2) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Bueno me gustaría saber lo que me esta pasando y muchas gracias. Soy nuevo en esto y aun me cuesta coger la lógica de todo esto y si necesitáis ayuda os echare una mano en lo que pueda. Saludos aqui esta el ejercicio : 5) Escribe un programa que lea un número n entero comprendido entre 1 y 9, e imprima una pirámide de números con
n filas como en la siguiente figura:

Comment: Si te fijas, solo sumas, no restas, te falta otro for

Comment: y como lo puedo hacer le estoy dando vuelta pero nada

Comment: Puedes con un for que el limite sea `2*max-1` y dentro dos que aumente hasta 9 y otro que decrezca, mas lo que tienes

Comment: lo voy a mirrar

Comment: listo ya solo me falta darle la vuelta

Comment: Nicolas abajo descubri la respuesta muchas gracias por la ayuda por la piista que me diste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar el error el fichero que estaba editando no era ese si no este

```
package examen1Tr;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author javie
 */
public class Ejercicio5 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        // obtenemos el valor recibido
        System.out.print("Escribe un numero del 1 al 9 : ");
        int filas = teclado.nextInt();
        if (filas < 1 || filas > 9) {
            System.out.println("ERROR. Debe introducir un número entero entre 1 y 9.");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= filas; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= filas - i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```